# How do I ensure that security updates are installed on Juju machines?

Tags: updates, security, juju

It seems that security updates and other package updates are not automatically installed in Juju nodes. I assume that they are installed at installation of new Juju machines, or that the installation media is a daily updated version of Ubuntu.

How do I ensure that updates are installed in all machines?

And what about reboots to install kernel updates?

Answer (score 3):

I think currently the options are:

- Log into each node regularily and do package updates manually
- Use Landscape (requires a subscription). There is a landscape client charm: http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/landscape-client
- For each node, manually do one of these alternatives using SSH login: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates#Using_the_.22unattended-upgrades.22_package (easiest is probably just to run "sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades" and answer yes on all nodes)

This might be discussed here: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/security-r-juju-charms.

Whishlist:

- Global environment/service/machine option to do automatic updates
- Unattended updates subordinate charm to associate with nodes I want to automatically update. Seems it is made here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+bug/1160736 and it waiting to be included in Charm store.

Comment: can't you do this with a cron job as well?

Comment: Where would that cron job run then? Somewhere and then log into all instances and do the updates? Remember that services could consist of many units and frequently be removed and added.

Comment: Hmm, hours after I enabled unattended upgrades, I still see "5 packages can be updated.
5 updates are security updates."...